# Why does the break point not disappear when removed

Tags: delphi, debugging, breakpoints, delphi-2007

Using D2007.  Sometimes **breakpoints** will not disappear.  I can remove them from the unit and run the program; and the debugger will break because the **breakpoint** has resurrected itself.

If I remove the breakpoint and close and reopen the file, it comes back.

I did discover what the issue was some years ago.  But I can no longer remember.  Does anyone has a clue ?

Comment: What IDE add-ons do you have installed?

Comment: @JerryDodge  MMX, GExperts and DDevExtensions.  But I have always had them.  Nothing has changed in the IDE or the addons.

Comment: I'm not familiar with D2007 or any of those add-ons, but I have had issues with later versions of Delphi which were fixed by disabling or uninstalling one of them. For example, one IDE issue was fixed by uninstalling AQTime since I never used it, and another issue was fixed by not starting Castalia with DXE8.

Comment: Delete it from the dsk file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember now that I deleted them from the **Breakpoints View** last time.  I decided to try the file deletion as suggested by David.

I changed to a different project group, deleted the breakpoints section from the **dsk** file of the original project group and switched back.  But the breakpoints came back.  So I exited the IDE and deleted that section and restarted - and now they are gone.

I was intrigued as to why this happened, so I looked at the backup of the dsk file.  I discovered the breakpoints were pointing to files on the **C drive** which is where the source used to be.  I shifted them to the **E drive** a few years ago when I went to Windows 7.

It would appear that when it applies them it disregards the drive.  But when you try to delete them, it tries to match the whole path.

Comment: Delphi not only disregards the drive, but also the directory. So if you have two units with the same name (eg if you have two 'generated' projects that create 'Main.PAS') open at the same time Delphi will get confused and show break points that are not there and break at points you don't expect. Sometimes when you click on an apparent breakpoint a green tick appears (meaning the breakpoint has been successfully added, even though it was already apparently there) and clicking again makes it disappear. This was all true on D2009. Whether it has been fixed for XE I am not sure, but I doubt it.